# Jest compare object with arbitrary property value

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, integration-testing

I'm testing rest API with Jest. I know we use `toEqual` to check whether two objects are equal or not by recursively compare all the properties.

For primitive values `toEqual` uses `Object.is` for the comparison.

#### Problem

The problem I'm having is while testing `/register` endpoint. After once a user successfully registered, the endpoint returns the user details. Use details contain information like phone, name, email, and what is more important in this case a *user_id*.

Now, what I'm trying is like this:

```js
const data = {
  sponsor_id: 'ROOT_SPONSOR_ID',
  phone: '9999999999',
  name: 'Joe',
  password: 'shhhhh'
};

// Some API call goes here which returns `body`

expect(body).toEqual({
  user_id, // <-- How to test value of this?
  sponsor_id: data.sponsor_id,
  phone: data.phone,
  name: data.name
});
```

I don't know beforehand what would be the returned value of `user_id` field. All I know that it would be a Number. Now it can be any numeric value so how to test an object property with any value or any numeric value in this case?

**One thing that I also wanted to check that I'm sending any extra data (properties) than what I'm expecting.** Which by the way using `toEqual` is taking care of already.

If my approach of the way I'm testing this is flawed then please provide me with a better one with some explanation.

Comment: how about using [`objectContaining`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectobjectcontainingobject)?

Comment: @skyboyer In that case only a **subset** of data in the `body` will be tested.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [`expect.any(Number)`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectanyconstructor) to ensure that `user_id` is a `Number`:

```
test('matches', () => {

  const data = {
    sponsor_id: 'ROOT_SPONSOR_ID',
    phone: '9999999999',
    name: 'Joe',
    password: 'shhhhh'
  };

  const user_id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
  const body = Object.assign(data, { user_id });

  expect(body).toEqual({
    user_id: expect.any(Number),  // user_id must be a Number
    sponsor_id: data.sponsor_id,
    phone: data.phone,
    name: data.name,
    password: data.password
  });  // SUCCESS

});
```

---

Note that if you want an even more specific matcher you can [create your own](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectextendmatchers) using `expect.extends`.